# Json serialization with timezone

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a json like this

```
{
    ...
    "date":"2022-02-28T00:00:00+01:00"
    ...
}
```

and the JsonSerializerSettings

```
new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Formatting = Formatting.None,
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
});
```

when the json is deserialized in the class that contain the date property the value is 2022-02-27 at 23:00.
How should I change JsonSerializerSettings to get the same value in the object, so 2022-02-28?

Comment: It probably **is** the same time, just expressed in UTC rather than GMT+01:00. Remember, `2022-02-28T00:00:00+01:00` (standard European time) equals `2022-02-27T23:00:00Z` (UTC).

Comment: Yes are the same, but I want the same date, the same timezone.

Comment: The code is working fine.  VS is displaying the results in your machine local culture and nothing is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

By default, NewtonsoftJson parses to a [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime), which doesn't contain timezone information. But you can set the [`DateParseHandling` option](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_DateParseHandling.htm) to `DateTimeOffset` instead (list of possible options for the setting [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DateParseHandling.htm)). [`DateTimeOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset) is a type that includes timezone information.

So:

```
new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Formatting = Formatting.None,
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
    DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset,
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I think that this work fine with a json like 2022-02-28T00:00Z, with Z at the end. But my json is 2022-02-28T00:00:00+01:00 with +01:00 at the end. I can't change the source json.

Comment: @user3401335 - What makes you think it won't work with `2022-02-28T00:00:00+01:00`?

Comment: @user3401335 - I just tried it, and it worked just fine.